# Matching Two Array Indexes - c# / Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a program which will substitute a character in place of another. I have created two arrays, odd and even as follows:

```
char[] odd = { 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'q', 's', 'u', 'w', 'y' };
char[] even ={ 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z' };
```

Now, if the input is *'a'*, it has to put *'b'* and if the input is *'b'*, it has to print *'a'*.

So i thought it is best to match the index of both the arrays since they have equal count. the basic idea is this :

the input is *'a'*, so the compiler takes the index of *'a'* - 0 into account and substitutes the value at even with the index 0 - *'b'*.

so I thought of assigning a spare character *'j'*, which will find the index of the input and outputs the corresponding character from the array - `even[]`.

I tried few times but could not get a solution. Kindly help me in this...

This is what I have tried.

The desired input maybe like this : Hello
The desired output should be this:  Gfkkp

This supposedly gives me the desired result.

```
private void superSecretFormula(string myName)  
{
    string read = myName;
    int count = read.Length;

    char[] odd = { 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'q', 's', 'u', 'w', 'y' };
    //char[] j;

    char[] even = { 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z' };
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13 ; j++)
        {
            if (read[i]==odd[j])
            {
                int k = j;
                textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + Convert.ToString(char.ToUpperInvariant(even[k]));
            }
            if (read[i] == even[j])
            {
                int k = j;
                textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + Convert.ToString(char.ToUpperInvariant(odd[k]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly comment on the quality and approach in solving this problem, as I am a newbie and I am starting to learn code only now. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your substitutions are unique I would consider changing your structure to something like this to ease the usage.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subs = new Substitutes {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}};

        Console.WriteLine(subs['a']); //Prints b
        Console.WriteLine(subs['b']); //Prints a
    }

    class Substitutes : Dictionary<char, char>
    {
         public new void Add(char item, char substitute)
         {
             base.Add(item, substitute);
             base.Add(substitute, item);
         }
    }
}
```

Now substituting all chars in a string would be trivial by just checking if the key exists.

Comment: While this code is short and works well, in general it is not very robust to inherit from `Dictionary` in cases like this. Somebody might call `((Dictionary<char,char>)subs).Add('x','y');` and they'll get a broken mapping. It's better to implement `IDictionary<char,char>` and use a `Dictionary` as a private member.

Comment: But I have to do it for every character , ie a-z right? I am trying to avoid that way..

Comment: @ArunHariharan: Do what for every character? It's not clear what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @Gabe Never mind, I misread the Solution. :) Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly where you need help. A small function that substitutes every character of a string that is contained in `odd` by the respective one in `even` and vice versa could look like:

```
static char[] odd = { 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'q', 's', 'u', 'w', 'y' };
static char[] even = { 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z' };

static string Substitute(string input)
{
    char[] result = new char[input.Length];
    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;
    foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
    {
        found = false;
        result[i] = c;
        for (int j = 0; j < odd.Length; j++)
        {
            if (odd[j] == c)
            {
                result[i] = even[j];
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < even.Length; j++)
            {
                if (even[j] == c)
                {
                    result[i] = odd[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return new string(result);
}
```

You can also optimize this, by creating some sort of mapping from every input character to the output character, that only has to be created once and is cached then:

```
static char[] odd = { 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'q', 's', 'u', 'w', 'y' };
static char[] even = { 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z' };
static int[] mapping = null;

static string Substitute(string input)
{
    if (mapping == null)
    {
        mapping = new int[Math.Max(odd.Select(x => (int)x).Max(), even.Select(x => (int)x).Max()) + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < mapping.Length; i++) mapping[i] = i;

        // Note: Make sure 'odd' and 'even' are arrays of the same length
        for (int i = 0; i < odd.Length; i++) mapping[(int)odd[i]] = (int)even[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < even.Length; i++) mapping[(int)even[i]] = (int)odd[i];
    }

    char[] result = new char[input.Length];
    int j = 0;
    foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
    {
        int charcode = (int)c;
        result[j] = charcode >= mapping.Length ? c : (char)mapping[charcode];
        j++;
    }
    return new string(result);
}
```

Comment: You could apply DRY and put the for loop into a shared method that you pass in odd first, then if not found pass in even.

Comment: @Michael: Youre right, that was just a quick and dirty snippet. Not elegant in any way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your original idea with the least modification.

```
Array.IndexOf(odd, 'a'); //will return 0
Array.IndexOf(odd, 'b')' //will return -1
```

so....

```
if(Array.IndexOf(odd, inputChar) > -1 )
{
    Console.WriteLine(even[Array.IndexOf(odd, inputChar)]);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(odd[Array.IndexOf(even, inputChar)]);
}
```

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a class that holds references to two dictionaries containing the letters that should be transposed; similar to the OP's original two arrays. And then create a method to convert an input string:

```
public class TransposeLetters
{
    public Dictionary<char, char> Odd { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<char, char> Even { get; private set; }

    public TransposeLetters()
    {
        Odd = new Dictionary<char, char>();

        // capital leters
        for( int i = 65; i <= 90; i += 2 )
        {
            Odd.Add( (char)i, (char)( i + 1 ) );
        }

        // small letters
        for( int i = 97; i <= 122; i += 2 )
        {
            Odd.Add( (char)i, (char)( i + 1 ) );
        }

        Even = Odd.ToDictionary( x => x.Value, x => x.Key );
    }

    public string Convert( string str )
    {
        // ensure only letters are passed into the method
        var cleansed = str.Where( char.IsLetter );

        var transposed = cleansed.Select( x => Odd.ContainsKey( x ) ? Odd[x] : Even[x] );

        var result = new string( transposed.ToArray() );

        return result;
    }
}
```